# Python not working on windows command line?

Tags: python, windows

I'm at wit's end here!

I have both of these: `C:\Python34\` and `C:\Python33\`

I have added `C:\Python34\` to the Path system variable, and I tried creating it as PYTHONPATH as well, neither of these worked. Yes of course I restarted the command line, then I even tried restarting the computer.

What could I try next? I don't know how to "debug" system problems like this.

`python` and `python3` (the two candidate command names) are still both unrecognized commands to the Windows command line.

---

`echo %PATH%` gives this:

```
C:\Users\Aerovistae>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Wi
Fi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Comp
onents\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:
\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\OpenAFS\Comm
on;C:\Program Files\OpenAFS\Client\Program;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Users\Aerovist
ae\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\cmd;C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\GitHub\Por
tableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\bin;C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\2711ZE2V.R4O\7RBECTVA.7T9\gi
th..tion_317444273a93ac29_0001.0000_64b63662dd016e14;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppDat
a\Local\Apps\2.0\2711ZE2V.R4O\7RBECTVA.7T9\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0001.0000_64b63662dd016e14\NativeBinaries/x86;C:/Postg
reSQL/9.2/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Prog
ram Files\nodejs\; C:\Python34\;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:
\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Python33;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm
```

`python` returns `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Same with `python3`.

Comment: what is theoutput of `echo %PATH%` and `python` command? could you paste it here?

Comment: Edited to include output

Comment: If I navigate INTO the Python34 folder it works....

Comment: You didn't show us real output. We need to see the real output.

Comment: In command line what's the output of `where python` ? It should list your python directory if PATH is configured correctly.

Comment: There you go....python34 and python33 both are in there

Comment: Do you have `python` executable in `C:\Python34\` or `C:\Python33\` ? Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current environment's `%PATH%` has `c:\python34` the python command would be recognised if there is executable named `python` in `c:\python34`.

Check if there is a `python.exe` inside `c:\python34`. if not, find where in `c:\python34` it exists. if the directory is `c:\python34\some\path` add `c:\python34\some\path` in your `%PATH%`

Also check if your python executable and the os is of same bit. I mean both should either be 32-bit or 64-bit. One can not recognize other.

Comment: There is indeed that executable inside that folder.

Comment: Okay it just started working. I'm at a total loss. I added it to path all over again and it mysteriously works now.